colombian with USA/colombian passport with 5 month till passport expires
I have a trip to colombia i have dual citizenship USA/colombian . I know i can enter no problem but leaving colombia it says it has to be with a passport of at least 6 months and I have 5 left. I am trying to make the appointment in the consulate but it is almost impossible every time i try to make an appointment it says there is no availiability or error. would it be a problem ? and no i cant renew the passport there.

So you are trying to renew your Colombian passport?  Do you also have a US passport, and can you use that to travel to Colombia?

"but leaving colombia it says it has to be with a passport of at least 6 months" What says that?
